# Unable to start a New web VB project in Visual studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to start a new Web project in VS 2013 And When I am trying to do that I am getting the following error

```
Configuring IISExpress failed Due to the following problem
 File name:redirection.config
 Error :Cannot read the configuration file
```

I have tried like reinstalling IIS express, and Deleteing the IIS folder in my Documents and I could not find any Files inside `raj\Documents\IISExpress\config`

I am using windows 7
So can any one tell me how to solve this issuse.

Comment: Check this post: http://forums.asp.net/post/5609231.aspx

Comment: I have tried But it is still the same.

Comment: You did try deleting `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config `?

Comment: yes I tried it and I could not find any files inside config Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution.
Need to copy The files `C:/programfiles/IISexpress/config/template/personwebserver/` and copy the files `applicationhost.config , aspnet.config , redirection.config` files to `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config`

Then It will work. And it worked for me as well. I hope this one will help somebody here to solve the problem.